# Test for incidence-rate trend in Stata

Tags: trend, incidence-rate-ratio

I am using Stata 17.0 MB and working on a dataset of Enterococci bacteria infections in the previous ten years (2012–2021). These bacteria have more dangerous subtypes resistant to one antibiotic (vancomycin; hence called VRE).

I want to test whether there is a significant trend in the incidence rate of these subtypes over the previous ten years.

What is the appropriate statistical test I have to use to check whether the noted increase in the incidence rate is statistically significant in Stata?

My dataset and variables are illustrated below. Thank you in advance

[image: Variables description]
[image: Incidence over years]

Comment: In each year there is a given number of Enterococcae $n_{allE}$ of which the $n_{VRE}$ is a part and what you call incidence rate is $n_{VRE}/n_{allE}$. This could be modelled as the probability p in a Binomial process. Use a binomial GLM with the probability $p$ being linearity dependent on the number of the year.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help,,

I'm using stata 17, how can I fit model in same manner you have suggested?

Comment: I don't own or know stata but google tells me *"Probit model of y events as a function of x using grouped data with group sizes n
glm y x, family(binomial n) link(probit)"*. Cited from https://www.stata.com/manuals/rglm.pdf As far as I understand replace y by VRE, x by year and n by total number of Enterococcae.

Comment: Than you so much